# Using AND on same key in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a key in my document whose structure is as follow:

```
"tag": [
    {
      "schemeName": "http:\/\/somesite.com\/categoryscheme2",
      "name": "Test Tag2",
      "value": 1,
      "slug": "test_tag2"
    },
    {
      "schemaName": "http:\/\/somesite.com\/categoryscheme3",
      "name": "Test Tag3",
      "value": 1,
      "slug": "test_tag3"
    }
  ]
```

Now, I get inputs as `tag=test_tag2ANDtest_tag3`. How can I write a query for this?
I tried to iterate through the loop but I didnt got any results.

Comment: Have you tried writing a query? Have you looked at [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/), it even has an online tutorial, complete with basic mongo shell

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes..I tried this: conditions['tag.slug'] = {'$and' : tags} where tags is the array contaiong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but you don't need an `$and` or `$elemMatch`, instead:

```
$mongodb->collection->find(array('tags.slug'=>array(
    '$in' => array('test_tag2','test_tag3'))))
```

Should work, however, if your English suggests what a second read does, then you can also use `$all` in place of `$in`. This will ensure that all root documents must have those slugs in them.

Comment: Does $in act as a OR and $all as a AND??

Comment: @SankalpMishra Effectively yes

Comment: Just one more question!!,, Can i use $all for a certain array and $in for certain in one go?/

Comment: @SankalpMishra Yes, you can use both operators, wouldn't make much sense if on the same array but as you suggest on different arrays it is more than possible, glad to have helped :)

Comment: i get query string as t1&t2&t3|t5|t6. Here i need to use and and or both..thatis the reason!! Any suggestions on this??

Comment: @SankalpMishra `find(($or => array(array('tags.slug'=>array('$in'=>array('t1','t2','t3'))), array('tags.slug'=>'t5'), array('tags.slug'=>'t6'))))` Unfortunately that is the closest I can think of `:/`

Comment: yes that is what i am actually doing...but $or give OperationFailure error in python!!!

Comment: @SankalpMishra In python? hmm will need to test this a little

Answer (score 0):

use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) operator to match elements inside the array.

Comment: I tried this and got :  OperationFailure: database error: $elemMatch needs an Object.  my query was : conditions['tag.slug'] = {'$elemMatch' : tags}

Comment: db.collection.find( { 'tag' : { $elemMatch: { 'name' : 'Test Tag3' } })

Comment: I am getting tag names as an array. How can i put array in this condition??